# Does Akamai redirect pages based on cookie?

Tags: redirect, cookies, akamai

The website I am maintaining requires that users enter their age and country on a form before being able to access the contents on it.

This creates a cookie and the user doesn't need to go through the form again to access the pages on the website.

However, I need to create a page where the user is not required to go through this form even if the cookie doesn't exist.

After investigating, I found that AkamaiGhost is doing the redirection to the form if the cookie does not exist.

I tried to create the cookie automatically when the page loads, but Akamai still redirects the page before even allowing the page to create the cookie.

I am not very familiar with Akamai but I wish to know if Akamai can check for the cookies before redirecting the pages on the website. If so, how can I prevent this for this particular page?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted Akamai directly and the redirection was obviously being done by them. They solved my issue.